# Inserting bulk of data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert  data with the same input's "name".
For example

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PageController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img[]">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>   
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I want to get the following result

```
ID|page_id|name|img
1 |15     |1   |file1.jpg
2 |15     |2   |file2.jpg
3 |15     |3   |file3.jpg
```

Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
   if($request->hasFile('img')){
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
        $pathToStore = $request->file('img')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
    }

   $info = new Info;
   $info->name = $request->input('Name');
   $info->img = $fileNameToStore;
   $info->page_id = $page->id; 
   $info->save();   
}
```

BTW I made some test, and I my values didn't even return if I use

> name="img[]"

but if I use code below it works,but returns only the last input data

> name="img"

```
$info = new Info;
   $name = $info ->name = $request->input('name');
   $img = $info ->img = $fileNameToStore;
   $id = $baninfo er->company_id = $company->id; 

   return $reqs = [$name,$img,$id];
```

Will return the following code

```
[["name 1","name 2"],"123_1504558228.jpg",133]
```

But I'm expecting to get 2 images instead of the last input img...
Any tips how to insert data like this?

Answer (score 0):

Heey myJuune,

I think your problem is in your line of code shown down below.

```
if($request->hasFile('img')){
```

When you put `img[]` in your view it automagically creates an array. The thing you're forgetting is to loop over the array of images. `$request->get('img')` currently represents an array of images.

If you use `dd($request->get('img'));` you should see an array of images. (When you're using `img[]` on your input of course).

Your code should work when you're doing it like this: (I'm assuming the `name` array is has the same length as the `img` array, because the array keys of the `img` array are being use to retrieve the name value. You can also see I put your DB record creation proces inside the loop, because you're associating the names with the images.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
       if($request->has('img')) {

          foreach($request->get('img') as $key => $img)
            $fileNameExt = $img->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $fileExt = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
            $pathToStore = $img->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);

           $info = new Info;
           $info->name = $request->input('Name')[$key];
           $info->img = $fileNameToStore;
           $info->page_id = $page->id; 
           $info->save(); 

        }

       }
```

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, it might help me.
At this moment after submitting the form everything works but it doesn't save data to DB
Edited: I tested dd($request->get('img')); and it returns NULL

Comment: Hi myJuune, my apologies for my late response. I'm curious whether you already found a solution to your problem? Maybe you could invite me to collaborate on Github so I could help you? If you want another answer with a solution, I could also post a new answer. (My setup could be a bit different from yours, but I don't expect the problem to be around your setup)